# Global LaunchAgent implementation on macOS

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-daemon, launchdagent

I have been trying to implemented a working global launch agent which can work across multiple users, but I cannot get it to the finish line. It is working for a single user perfectly but when switched to a different user the launch agent is failing with `exit code 78 - function not implemented` and cannot understand anything from the error. below is my plist

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.company.agent</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/runscript.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have placed the launch agent at `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.company.agent.plist` and when I run `ls -al /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.company.agent.plist`, I get
`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  752 Jan 21 13:27 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.company.agent.plist`

The permissions of the /Library/LaunchAgents are `drwxr-xr-x    8 root  wheel   256 Jan 21 13:32 /Library/LaunchAgents`

I am using this command to load the agent `/bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.company.agent.plist`

When I run `ls -al /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/runscript.sh`, I get `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  227 Jan 21 13:28 /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/runscript.sh`.

The content of the runscript.sh is

```
#! /bin/sh
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Calendar"
   activate
end tell
EOF
```

Entire configuration seems fine as per other stackoverlfow recommendations, and the launch agent works great on the first user, but as soon as I try to load it from the second user it is failing with 78 exit code, I really appreciate your input, thanks.

Comment: The error code is from the kernel, so it would be worth starting to identify if the problem is executing the script, or the code in the script. Perhaps changing the script to output to the Console's Unified Logging and adding stdout and stderr to the plist would help identify this; see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/183589/how-do-i-activate-launchd-logging-on-os-x)

Comment: thanks I will check on that, and update